# What to do when in a Western country a member of the opposite sex tries to shake hands?

Tags: non-muslim-countries, men-women, physical-contact

If in a Western country a member of the opposite sex stretches his/her hand with the intention of shaking hands (as a greeting), how should a Muslim behave?

Comment: Explain your point of view or shake hands you must evaluate the situation and make your decision!